# How should I document Python method parameters so they appear in intellisense and DOxygen?

Tags: python, intellisense, doxygen, pvts

I've been using PyTools for Visual Studio 2013 and am wondering if it's possible to document paramaters in such a way that both intellisense and DOxygen understand them.

For example I've been trying like this (snippet taken from [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)):

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)
    """

    print("Test func running")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    complex(
```

...but Intellisense doesn't seem to pick up the argument descriptions:

[image]

Comment: Last time I tried to use PyTools for Visual Studio, things like Intellisense and even proper code highlighting weren't really very good at all.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to Intellisense, but I have used doxygen with Python.  You can use documentation strings as you have done, but it won't pick up doxygen's symbols to parse out various parts of the documentation.   If you need that, you would want to do something like this:

```
    ##
    # @brief Form a complex number.
    #    
    # Keyword arguments:
    # @param real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    # @param imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    print("Test func running")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    complex(
```

There is a little bit of description here http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html  Near the bottom of the page.

However, I would suggest using an IDE made for Python such as PyCharm instead of Visual Studio.   It will give you a lot of Python oriented tools VS doesn't have including intellisense-type functionality for Python.